# receiving large amount of data from serial port in c# and using progressbar

Tags: c#, serial-port

My serial port is receiving large amount of data that needs  about 5 seconds to complete transfer data. I want to use a progress bar in C#.

**How can I recognize end of data transfer for applying progress bar?**

(size of data is constant and clear)

Comment: If you know the amount of data, and the data rate you can estimate time remaining. But as the data rate can easily change it will only be an *estimate*. TimeRemaining = DataLeft / DataRate.

Comment: How do you expect *us* to know what the end looks like?  If you can't count off bytes or have a special end-of-data marker then you just don't know when it is done.  If you can't count off bytes then you cannot possible know how long it will take, so displaying reliable progress isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using the `System.IO.SerialPort` class? In case of 'yes', the `SerialPort` class has a `DataReceived` event:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived.aspx

Which fires each time you receive data over the serial port. Now let's say you know you need to receive 5 bytes. Before starting to receive data you set your progress bar's maximum value to 5:

```
progressBar1.Maximum = 5;
```

Then, when you receive data, increase the progress bar with the amount of data you received:

```
    private static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
    int BytesReceivedCount = sp.BytesToRead;

    if(InvokeRequired)
    {
        Invoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            progressBar1.Value += BytesReceivedCount;
        }));
    }
    else
        progressBar1.Value += BytesReceivedCount;
}
```

Comment: `DataReceived` in async. You cannot update UI controls in that method. Use `Invoke` instead.

Comment: Ah damn, that's true. Updating my answer.

Answer (score 0):

[SerialPort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx) class of .net framework can easily do that for you. It supports both synchronous and asynchronous transfer modes. Use asynchronous mode for your case and use `DataReceived` event to update your progress bar. It will simply be (TotalBytesReadTillNow / TotalDataSize) * 100. Assign this to `progressbar.value`.

Also note that in asynchronous programming, you cannot update your controls or other UI stuff from non-UI threads. Use `Invoke` to update your UI.

The link above has a good example included.